# undefined reference to error only for certain functions

Tags: go, cgo, cflags, ldflags

I have a library and a C interface built for it.
My program compiles just fine with `versionString()` but not with `loadConfig()`. How is that possible?

**walker.h** :

```
#ifndef WFE_C_H
#define WFE_C_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

  const char* versionString();

  void* loadConfig(const char *filePath, char* errorMessageBuffer, int bufferLen);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

**Working version**:

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -Isrc/walker
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/lib -lwalker
#include "walker.h"
*/
import (
    "C"
)
func main() {
    p := C.versionString()
    version := C.GoString(p)
    fmt.Println(version)
}
// output: v1.94
```

**Not working version**:

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -Isrc/walker
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/lib -lwalker
#include "walker.h"
*/
import (
    "C"
)
func main() {
    errorMessageBuffer := C.CString("")
    pathPtr := C.CString("/src/vali/config")
    bufferLen := C.int(len(4000))

    C.loadConfig(pathPtr, errorMessageBuffer, bufferLen)
}
```

**Traceback**:

```
/tmp/go-build056292810/github.com/testong/vali/_obj/main.cgo2.o: In 
function `_cgo_b2bd1c9e3dda_Cfunc_loadConfig':
/tmp/go-build/github.com/testong/vali/_obj/cgo-gcc-prolog:43: undefined 
reference to `loadConfig'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Is the example correct? Where is `C.loadConfigDirectory` defined?

Comment: I amended the walker.h, I made a typo sorry

Answer (score 0):

In `walker.h` , the export function is 
`void* loadConfig(const char *filePath, char* errorMessageBuffer, int bufferLen);`

And you used `C.loadConfigDirectory(pathPtr, errorMessageBuffer, bufferLen)`.

The function `loadConfigDirectory` is not defined.

Maybe it is a typo?

Working version works because `versionString` is already defined.

Comment: @thylong Can you give the implementation? I doubt that you don't implement `loadConfig`.